# Does curl_exec stop program execution?

Tags: php, node.js, curl, callback

I am new to using PHP to make web requests. Previously I have only ever used node.js.

In node, our program continues to run after we send the web request. When the response comes back, then node automatically runs the callback function associated with the request.

However on PHP, I see that I can make a web request by calling curl_exec on my curl object. But how do I get the callback? What if I need to keep running code between the time when the request has been sent, and when it comes back? Is there a way to basically do a callback through some other method?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

In PHP most functions are blocking, the program execution halts until the operation finished. This is the case with `curl_exec`.

You get the returned response (or a boolean indicating success) as the return value of the function. See the [manual on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php#refsect1-function.curl-exec-returnvalues):

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure.

Comment: It appears the OP already knows that `curl_exec` halts the execution. They are looking for an alternative solution that doesn't halt the code execution.